# Plot two columns based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1,2,3],
                    'number' :[4,5,6],
                    'points': [10000,20000,30000]})
```

What is the easiest way to plot a figure that shows the relationship between number and points in each year? (i.e., x-axis is "number" , y-axis is "points" and legend is "year")

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.lineplot(data=df, x='number', y='point', hue='year')`.

Comment: Thanks Quang. Is there a way to do that in matplotlib?

Comment: `df.pivot(index='number', columns='year', values='point').plot()`.

Comment: Just a quick question, how can I show the legend in the matplotlib version?

Comment: `ax = df.pivot(...).plot(); ax.legend()`?

Comment: Legend is automatically added on my system, without `ax.legend`.

Comment: I had to manually add the years

Answer (score 0):

I like using holoviews, you can use hvplot (https://hvplot.holoviz.org/)
for this:

```
import hvplot.pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1,2,3],
                    'number' :[4,5,6],
                    'points': [10000,20000,30000]})
df.hvplot.scatter(x='number', y='points', color='year', clabel='year')
```

output:

[image]